# How do I recover a BTRFS filesystem with "parent transid verify failed" errors?

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs

I've got an external USB disk running btrfs. I use it for backups, and each time I do a backup I take a snapshot.

However, it's giving me this error now:

```
parent transid verify failed on 109973766144 wanted 1823 found 1821
parent transid verify failed on 109973766144 wanted 1823 found 1821
```

Obviously, this is a non-critical disk, but I have a few files on here that aren't available elsewhere. Is there any way to recover data from this disk? Maybe by mounting one of the snapshots as root?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/157917/how-do-i-recover-a-btrfs-partition-that-will-not-mount.